# 1980s(?) Short story about a Martian colonist who is offered the chance to become a sentient star

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story many years ago, probably as a short story in a science fiction magazine in the 80's.

It was a fantastic story that took place in the near future on a colony on Mars where a disease had taken over Earth and moved onto killing the remaining colonists of Mars.

The main character goes to something that was described like a holodeck that repeatedly produced a hologram about a man playing a piano in his ship.

Later he meets a super-intelligent being or beings that offers him the chance to escape his mortal coil and experience the universe in their perception of time. He transcends his body and becomes a star and witnesses cosmic time and the rise and fall of galaxies, cosmic timescales and the history of other beings.

It wasn't written by Isaac Asimov but I do think it was in one of his publications.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 3):

I found it [Understanding Space and Time](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/27793041-understanding-space-and-time) by Alastair Reynolds.

[image]

Comment: Neat! Can we encourage you into [edit]ing a summary/quotes that matched wat you remembered? :) this would make for a better answer, more likely to help people looking for the same thing

Comment: Could you also confirm where you originally read it? It might help future askers who remember it as part of the same anthology...